# OS X 10.8 can't resize partitions on MBR disk

Tags: macos, partitioning, osx-mountain-lion

I have an external HD with a mix of Mac, NTFS and Linux partitions.
I wanted to use it to backup some partitions from my MacBook HD, and partially succeeded, copying a 100MB partition into an empty 300MB partition. 
Unfortunately Disk Utility won't let me resize partitions, or create any new partitions, giving the following message.

```
You can't resize partitions on this disk because it uses the Master Boot Record partition scheme.
```

Is there any way around this?
None of my Windows partition programs can do anything with the Mac OS Extended partition.
Can I convert to GUID Partition Table and still use with Windows XP?

I don't want to lose the content of the NTFS partition, which contains years worth of backups.

PS Is this a new issue with Mountain Lion? I thought I had done these on Snow Leopard.

Comment: The only way I know is to conver the MBR disk to a GPT disk.  I would backup your data incase something happened.  What third-party tools have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting from MBR to GPT will render the disk unusable from Windows XP. A partial exception: The [GPT Mounter](http://www.mediafour.com/products/gptmounter) tool claims to enable Windows XP to mount GPT partitions; however, I've never tried it, so I can't comment on how well it works. If you do want to try an MBR-to-GPT conversion, my [GPT fdisk (`gdisk`, `sgdisk`, and `cgdisk`)](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) can do the job. So can some Windows-only tools, but I don't recall the details about them.

Overall, your best bet is probably to use GParted under Linux; you mention the disk has Linux partitions, so presumably you've got a Linux installation somewhere. If not, you could use a Linux emergency disc. In any event, GParted can resize most filesystems on both MBR and GPT disks.

One important caveat: Resizing partitions is inherently dangerous, so if you've got any irreplaceable data on the disk, back it up before you do anything. It sounds like you're using the disk as a backup storage medium, so you might instead simply be prepared to immediately make new backups if something goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer (and even more informative documentation on your site). My 2007 XP laptop won't support GPT, and I don't want to lose the backups of my genealogy data, so maybe it is time to get a new disk.